# Referencing a java class in its own constructor

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, constructor

I'm building a Java Swing class called ListView that attempts to be a general purpose list.

```
public class ListView<T> extends JPanel {
    private IListViewDataSource<T> dataSource;
    private JPanel list;

    public ListView(IListViewDataSource<T> dataSource, Dimension dimension) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;

        list = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.add(new JScrollPane(list));


        this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    }

    public void loadRows() {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSource.getNumberOfElements(); i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(dataSource.getTitleOfElement(dataSource.getElementAtPosition(i)));
            list.add(label);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do this, I declared an interface called IListViewDataSource that defines the methods required for the list view to obtain its data.

```
public interface IListViewDataSource<T> {
    T getElementAtPosition(int position);
    int getNumberOfElements();
    String getTitleOfElement(T element);
}
```

I wanted it to be possible to instantiate a new ListView with whichever DataSource you declare, in order to introduce whichever data in the list. So far so good.

Now, I'm building another class called OfferListView that extends ListView, and in order not to have an inneccessary extra file I wanted it to implement its own ListViewDataSource. The problem is that I can't call `super(this, dimension)` inside the constructor for this new class, as I'm then told that `this` can't be used before the superclass constructor has been called.

This "pattern" is what is used when programming with UIKit for iOS, and I think it's quite nice, but I can't get it to work in Java. How could I approach this?

Comment: First of all this  is not model view controller. Second if you want to keep your domain layer independent of view then you can do it with observer design pattern.

Comment: **EXTRA: ** In this kind of programming you don't need a controller , you can directly refer to domain objects but let domain object fire event. Check out how, for example, `PropertyChangeListener` works. Provide simply a subscribe function in domain that registers all elements which implements `PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I'm honestly inexperienced in java design patterns, so I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Could you give me an example?

Comment: example for seperating view from domain?

Answer (score 0):

`Domain-View-Controller` strategy was used in 90s on smaltalk to seperate view from domain and it is still being used in web-development.

Without writing all the classes for views etc, there are two ways for seperating view from domain.

(1st:) When view passes something to domain object then it keep `polling` to check for any additional changes. That means once a view object(a textfield, frame or anything else) has forwaded a request to domain it keeps checking after few seconds or minutes if something has changed. However this approach is not good.

(2nd:) The observer design pattern. When one thing changes it notifies automatically all listeners. Your view has to implement an interface and domain should provide a method for subscription for all objects which implement that interface. Here is an example and i did not compile it, However it clearly seperates `view` from `domain`.

```
public class View implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private DomainObject object;

    public View(DomainObject object) {
        assert(object != null);
        this.setObject(object);
    }

    public void enterText(String text) {
        this.getObject().update(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if(evt.getPropertyName().equals("string_updated"))
             System.out.println("New value is " + evt.getNewValue());
    }

    public DomainObject getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(DomainObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

}
```

Here is the domain class:

```
public class DomainObject {

    private String text;


    public DomainObject(String test) {
        this.setText(test);
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void update(String string) {
        this.setText(string);
        this.getListener().stream().forEach(e -> e.propertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this,"string_updated","",this.getText())));
    }

    private ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> listener;

    public void subscribe(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.getListener().add(listener);
    }


    public ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> getListener() {
        return listener;
    }


    public void setListener(ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


}
```

As i see, You are trying to have many views, if they are contained within eachother then use also `Composite design pattern`.

Comment: This is all for updating the list elements as they change right? I only wanted to provide the data for the list so that I can reuse ListView with different sets of data

Comment: What happends  when the list changes? It's fires an event which is caught by view and it's only view whether view shows it as a robot or a machine or as a string! Btw check 9 GRASP principles before learning design patterns.